# Can an entire $f$ satisfy $x>k | f(x+yi)=\ln(x+yi+z)+o(1) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, logarithms

Let $z$ be a complex number. Let $i$ be the imaginary unit. Let $x,y,k$ be positive real numbers.

Consider

$$x>k |  f(x+yi)=\ln(x+yi+z)+o(1)  $$

true for all $x>k,y$ and some $k,z$.

Is there an entire function $f$ that satisfies this ?

Comment: I do not understand your vertical line notation and I dislike the choice of variables. Are you saying that you are looking for an entire function $f(z) \sim \ln(z+a)$ for $\Re z$ sufficiently big?

Comment: In particular, what limit is the little o related to?

Comment: @Phira the vertical line means " for ... such that " It comes from set theory. And yes Im looking for $f(z)$ ~ $\ln(z+a)$.
The little o is not a limit but an upper bound. Its little o notation. I could write .... - .... =< 1 too but I prefer this o notation. I wanted to avoid writing $Re$ ( real part ) so I used x,y,k and defined them. It is equivalent.